# how to free the dynamically allocated memory for a local variable?

Tags: c

Sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void f(int n) {
     char *val = (char *) malloc(12*sizeof(char));
     val = "feels....";

     printf("%s", val);

 //  free val;     // if enable, compile time error: expected ';' before 'val'   free val;   
 }

 int main()
 {
      f(1);

      return 0;
 }
```

Is it required to free the memory which is dynamically allocated ? if yes, how to.

Comment: Write `free(val);` instead

Comment: With the code you show, you *can't!* You *reassign* the pointer to point somewhere else, leading to a leak and *undefined behavior* when you pass the pointer to the [`free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) *function*. If you want the allocated memory to contain a string then you have to [*copy* it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy). Remember that strings needs an extra character for the terminator, so a string of 12 characters needs space for 13.

Comment: Also, `<malloc.h>` is an obsolete header file, you should include `<stdlib.h>` for the `malloc` and `free` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to free the memory. But when you allocate memory for a string, the way to populate the string is not to assign a string to it as that replaces the memory you've allocated. Instead you're meant to use the function `strcpy` like this...

```
char *val = malloc(12*sizeof(char));
strcpy(val,"feels....");

printf("%s", val);
free(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
 char *val = (char *) malloc(12*sizeof(char));
 val = "feels....";  // val points now to the string literal ""feels...."
                     // discarding the value returned by malloc
 ...
 free(val);          // attempt to free the string literal which will
                     // result in undefined behaviour (most likely a crash)
```

you probably want this:

```
 char *val = malloc(12*sizeof(char));  // in C you don't cast the return value of malloc
 strcpy(val, "feels....");  // the string "feels...." will be copied into
                            // the allocated buffer
 ...
 free(val);          // free memory returned previously by malloc
```

Answer (score 1):

The compilation problem is because `free` is a function, you need to put its argument in parentheses.

```
free(val);
```

The other problem is a memory leak.

Strings in C are really just pointers to (hopefully) blocks of memory containing `char` data. The end of the string is denoted by a `char` with value 0. The thing to remember is that your variable is simply a pointer like any other pointer. So...

```
 char *val = (char *) malloc(12*sizeof(char));
```

The above line dynamically allocates a block of memory and assigns a pointer to it to `val`.

```
 val = "feels....";
```

The above line assigns a pointer to a string literal to `val` overwriting the previous pointer that was in `val`. It has not touched, in any way, the block of memory that was `malloc`ed in the first line. Furthermore, you have lost any reference you had to the `malloc`ed block so it has leaked. There's no way to `free` it.

String literals are usually created at compile time and the memory they occupy will be part of the program. This means they haven't come from the heap (where `malloc` gets its memory from. This means, in turn, when you try to `free` a string literal, bad things happen. On modern architectures, the program text is protected from writes at the OS level so trying to `free` part of it will almost certainly crash your program.

As long as you do not want to change the content of the string, you do not need to `malloc` space to it. You can omit the `malloc` line (and the corresponding `free`) and your program will still work.

f you do want to change the string, the easiest way to get a mutable copy of a string literal is to use `strdup`:

```
char *val = strdup("feels....");

// Do stuff with the string

free(val); // strdup strings need to be freed
```

`strdup` is a Posix function but not a C standard function so your platform might not have it. It's pretty simple to implement your own, though.

```
char* myStrDup(const char* thingToDup)
{
    char* ret = malloc(strlen(thingToDup) + 1); // strlen returns the length without the terminating nul. Hence add 1 to it to allocate
    strcpy(ret, thingToDup); // Copies the entire string including the terminating nul.
    return ret;
}
```